# Interjection for a longing sigh

Tags: single-word-requests, interjections

Is there an injection or at least an onomatopoeia for a longing sigh that works in writing? 
An example would be two colleagues are talking about the new member of the team on which one has a huge crush:

> [the word], he/she is soooo cute. I really should make a move.

All the positive interjections I know (oh, wow, phew, gee, awww) don't seem to work... at least for me (not a native speaker of English) To my perception, they are either too surprised, too amazed, to exhausted or too relieved. They are all not longing enough.

- Is there anything or is the only way **sigh* *?
- Could I use *sigh* in spoken English or does it only work in writing?

Comment: Sighs are real phonetic phenomena, so they're representable in IPA. However, since most people are innocent of phonetic representation, that's not helpful. There's no standard spelling for it, either, any more than there is for a fart. And **saying** "Sigh" in speech makes as much sense as **saying** "Fart". It's the real thing that has the effect, not its spoken name.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What meaning do you think your example ***soooo*** conveys that *isn't* effectively implying *too surprised, too amazed or to exhausted or too something else*?

Comment: @JohnLawler... that makes sense I guess, but in German it is possible to actually say "Seufz" to mean ... a sigh. It is on a meta level, if you will. You're not actually sighing but you would be in the situation you're talking about. An actual sigh is more connected to the here and now than is that "speechified" one. Anyway, I am looking for an equivalent for the German "Hach/Ach"

Comment: @fumblefingers... okay forget about the "too something else"... but neither of the injections I mentioned fit the context. It's hard to phrase why they don't but I hope you can see why I would say that they don't.

Comment: I might recommend another spelling of something you've already listed. For example, I think "Ooh" or "Ohh" could fit the bill, even if "Oh" doesn't; I might use "Ah" but not "AH!" (surprise), "Ahhh" (relief) or "AAH!" (fear).

Comment: Actually, "sigh" is used in spoken (US) English on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that when that feeling of longing and desire strikes, words just aren't adequate.

> A drawn out **mmmmmmmm-Mmmmmmmmm!"** should be understood to be an
>   expression of approval (with the emphasis on the 2nd Mmmmmmmm).
>
> OR
>
> A 2-note whistle, like a wolf call but kind of done under one's breath
>   also conveys the same meaning of "oh boy!".

If those suggestions aren't enough, a long, audible inhale followed by an equally long and audible exhale have the same meaning - if performed as part of the same interaction with the friend and the object of desire.

Comment: Is there any (commonly known/understood) way to capture the breathing thing in writing?

Comment: Maybe like this...."sssssnnnnniiiifffff, puhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" was the only sound poor, lovesick Joe made as he breathed in and out, slowly, deeply and with great longing".  The exhale should most definitely start with a soft "p" sound.

Comment: I think the O.P. is after the sound of a contented exhale. I'd probably spell that starting with an _h_, but, unfortunately, words like _heh_ and _huh_, which seem to be close aurally, are reserved for their sharper counterparts, usually uttered with contempt or derision. I think your exhale captures it, but how would we spell that?

Comment: @J.R., I know, right? It's that sound after the first "p" or "h" that is the tricky part.  I had to resort to descriptive words because everything else just sounded like a raspberry. lol!

Answer (score 0):

Onomatopoeia for a sigh of relief... whew! For example, "that was close" or "thank goodness that is over".

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a need for a longing sigh that does not appear to be adequately represented in the English language. J.R is correct, the best way forward would be to write an elongated sigh with a 'H' in front. But how to express a breathing sigh? Maybe try this?... Huhhhwwwm.